# How to draw a gif with expanding circles that reveal lines connecting a non-centered point to the expanding circle using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, physics

I’ve racked my brain for weeks trying to create a .gif which is a moving version of what the below diagram represents.
[image: radiation for accelerating charge]

The goal is to start with point (A) and (B) at the same position (origin) with the black lines diverging away from that point.

Then, shift (B) to the right to an arbitrary point. As (B) shifts right, it creates a pulse (the ring) that radiates outward.

As the ring radiates outward, it reveals the red lines, which diverge away from (B) as it moves.

My current progress is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \foreach\radius in{1,...,10}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\innerring{\radius/10-.08}
    \def\dottoinner{\radius/10+.08}
    \def\outerring{\radius/10}

    \draw [color=white] (-1,0) -- (1,0); %Used to keep frame the same size
    \draw [color=white] (0,-1) -- (0,1); %Used to keep frame the same size


    %When the dot is moving
    \ifnum\numexpr\radius<4
      %\draw [color=red] (\innerring, 0) -- (-\innerring,.2); %tried, failed, try again
      \draw [color=red] (\innerring, 0) -- (-\dottoinner,0);
      \node (A) at (\innerring, 0) [circle,fill,inner sep=.7pt]{};

    %Whent the dot is no longer moving
    \else
      %\draw [color=red] (.4-.08, 0) -- (-\innerring*.707,\innerring*.5); %tried, failed, try again
      \draw [color=red] (.4-.08, 0) -- (-\dottoinner,0);
      \node (B) at (.3, 0) [circle,fill,inner sep=.7pt]{};
    \fi

  %The pulse of radiation  
  \draw [thin] (0,0) circle[radius=\outerring] node (C) {};
  \draw [thin] (0,0) circle[radius=\innerring] node (D) {};

  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{document}
```

Which produces the gif:

[image]

The crux of the issue is that I can't seem to come up with an expression to relate the non-horizontal lines from the point (B) to the inner circle without having them change angles as the circles expands.

All packages are available to me for this project.

Comment: While I do not have a definitive answer yet (I have begun working on it) I assume that this is for illustrating how accelerating charges radiate away energy in the form of an EM wave?

Comment: @sabhoque Thank you for your time and yes--it is! I tried using arcs, and some trigonometry relating the vertical coordinate of point on the circle, but yet to solidify a good expression. I looked into polar coodinates with not the best results either.

Answer (score 11):

It is a very simple computation. The `x` coordinate of the circle center `B` is given by

```
  B_x = r * a ,
```

where `r` is the radius of the circle and `0<a<1` is a velocity. The rays emitted from `B` under an angle alpha have the parametrization

```
 gamma(t) = (B_x + t*cos(alpha), t*sin(alpha)) .
```

Their intersection with the circle around `A` of radius `r` can be obtained by demanding that

```
|gamma(t_crit)|^2 = r^2 .
```

This is a quadratic equation, which has a unique positive solution, a simple function `tcrit` that I punched in the following code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \R in {0.2,0.3,...,4.5}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=0.6; % velocity
 tcrit(\r,\ang)=(-2*a*\r*cos(\ang)+sqrt(2)*sqrt(\r*\r*(2-a*a+a*a*cos(2*\ang))))/2;}]
 \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
 \foreach \ang in {0,22.5,...,337.5}
 {\draw[very thick] (a*\R,0) -- ++(\ang:{tcrit(\R,\ang)}) -- 
 (\ang:1.2*\R) -- (\ang:10);}
 \draw[thick,even odd rule,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle[radius=\R] 
 circle[radius=1.2*\R];
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution (+1).

Comment: I recommend changing it to `\R+0.3` instead of `1.2*\R` because the inner and outer ring travel at the same speed. These changes can be ammended by changing the relevant sections to `{\draw[very thick] (a*\R,0) -- ++(\ang:{tcrit(\R,\ang)}) -- (\ang:\R+0.3) -- (\ang:10);}` and `\draw[thick,even odd rule,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle[radius=\R] circle[radius=\R+0.3];` . Nonetheless very good answer!

Comment: Strange, doing as I suggested results in the intermediate line cutting through the inner circle to get to the outer circle. I gues for artistic/diagramatic purposes as you have is more appropriate but for a more physically correct model `\R+0.3` is appropriate

Comment: @sabhoque Yes, that's a valid point. (I had `\R+0.2` in the first version of the answer.) Which one is more physical depends on the situation, though. You can emit two circles with different velocities. I do not know what physical situation we are trying to simulate here. (I gave +1 to your nice answer before I started writing this.)

Comment: From what I asked the OP it appears to be a simulation of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwZws.gif)

Comment: which is from [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126912/how-to-understand-accelerating-charge-radiate-using-intuition) an explanation as to why accelerating charges radiate EM waves

Comment: @sabhoque Yes, I didn't know that, thanks! If that is the case I agree. (The animation in the second link seems to be closer to mine.) I am not sure if this is the right way to describe the situation, i.e. I do not know if one should connect the inner and outer rays in the way it is done here. Rather, there should be a diffraction and the outer rays are not isotropic, I think.

Comment: yes I know what you mean and how the rays are curved which was the problem i was mentioning earlier. With straight lines the intermediate line crosses the inner circle to get to the outer circle which can be resolved with curved lines. But nonethless for illustrative purposes I think the model you proposed suffices

Comment: @sabhoque I do not necessarily think they will get curved. Rather, they will get diffracted depending on the impact angle. The impact angle is only 90 degrees for the rays emitted in the positive and negative x direction. For all others, the rays hit the circle under a nontrivial angle, i.e. the angle between a tangent at the circle and the ray is not 90 degrees. This gives you some refraction angle, but I do not see why the above prescription gives the correct one. Rather, I would expect the outer rays not to be isotropic, i.e. the angles between the rays are not constant.

Comment: hmm after doing some wider reading, I think that the inner shell moves along slightly with the charged particle (see these links [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=accelerating+charge+gif&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU821AU823&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYx7KFl7bjAhVM8XMBHTY4BdMQ_AUIECgB#imgrc=J63yCRjHisFGoM:) [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426608/why-does-an-accelerated-charge-radiate-away-energy)) such that its a circle with centre at the particle with a radius that increases at the same rate as the outer circle. Though I am certainly no expert in this field and am not sure.

Answer (score 7):

I am not particularly happy with this answer as it takes a long time to render and frame 1 and 3 is a bit dodgy (still trying to fix this) but here it is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
  \foreach\radius in{1,...,10}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
    \def\innerring{\radius/10-.08}
    \def\dottoinner{\radius/10+.08}
    \def\outerring{\radius/10}
    \def\dot{\radius/10-0.1}

    \node at (-1,-1) {};
    \node at (1,1) {};

    \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330} {
        \draw (\x:\outerring) -- (\x:1.5);
    }
    \draw [thin] (0,0) circle[radius=\outerring];
    \draw [thin] (0,0) circle[radius=\innerring];

    %When the dot is moving
    \ifnum\numexpr\radius<4
%      \draw [color=red] (\innerring, 0) -- (-\innerring,.2); %tried, failed, try again
%      \draw [color=red] (\innerring, 0) -- (-\dottoinner,0);
      \node (A) at (\dot, 0) [circle,fill,inner sep=2pt]{};
      \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330} {
            \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\innerring];
            \draw[name path=P1,red] (A) -- +(\x:5);
            \end{scope}
            \draw[name path=P2,draw opacity=0] (0,0) circle (\innerring);
            \path [name intersections={of=P1 and P2,by=E}];
            \draw[black!50] (E) -- (\x:\outerring);
        }


    %Whent the dot is no longer moving
    \else
      %\draw [color=red] (.4-.08, 0) -- (-\innerring*.707,\innerring*.5); %tried, failed, try again
%      \draw [color=red] (.4-.08, 0) -- (-\dottoinner,0);
      \node at (A) [circle,fill,inner sep=2pt]{};
      \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330} {
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\innerring];
        \draw[name path=P1,red] (A) -- +(\x:5);
        \end{scope}
        \draw[name path=P2,draw opacity=0] (0,0) circle (\innerring);
        \path [name intersections={of=P1 and P2,by=E}];
        \draw[black!50] (E) -- (\x:\outerring);
      }
    \fi

  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{document}
```

I based it off the image you had at the beginning

[image]